# Finding if intergral function is a constant function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and that 
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = (b-a) * max \{f(x) : x \in [a,b]\}$$ 
than $f(x)$ is a constant function in $[a,b]$.

How can I prove this one?

if $f(x)$ is a constant function in $[a,b]$ than there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ which for every $x \in [a,b] \implies f(x) = c $.

Let's assume that there an $x \in [a,b]$ where $f(x) \neq c$.

How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call $M=\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$. Then your condition can be expressed as
$$
\int_a^bM-f(x)dx=0.
$$
It is well known (and have been asked here at MSE several times) that the only continuous nonegative function whose integral is $0$ is the zero function so it must be $M-f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

**Edit:** Let $g$ be a continuous nonnegative  function on $[a,b]$. Suppose there exists $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $g(x_0)>0$. As $g$ is continuous there exists an open interval $I$ containing $x_0$ such that $g(x)>0$ for $x\in I$. As we can restrict to a smaller interval still containing $x_0$ we can suppose that $I$ is closed. Every continuous function on a compact set (which $I$ is) attains its minimum so it exists $m=\min_{x\in I}g(x)>0$ and then
$$\int_a^bg(x)dx\geq\int_Ig(x)dx\geq\int_Imdx=m|I|>0.$$

Comment: Thanks! but I can't use that it's well known and I'm not sure how I can prove that last part: " only continuous nonegative function ..." do you mind linking me to a resource or editing your answer instead?

Comment: Is it ok now?@DanRevah

Comment: great! thanks!!